# How to hide div after N seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to hide div after N seconds of the past after last pressing any key ?

```
<body onkeydown="KeyDown(event);" >

<div id="helpmenu"></div>
<script>
function KeyDown(event) {
    $('#helpmenu').show();
}
</script>
</body>
```

If I cannot press any key during 5 seconds: $('#helpmenu').hide()

Comment: Do you mean pressing any key anywhere on the form or when you press any key inside a text or select element?

Comment: of the past? after last? can you clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this).delay(2000, function()
{
    $('#mydiv').hide();
});
```

or...

```
setTimeout($('#mydiv').hide(), 2000);
```

Comment: +1: Really solid answer, but post a link to the `delay` plugin.

Comment: Ok... am going to sound stupid here I think... but delay is not a plugin... it's a part of the official release of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I actually was referring to this plugin I use that I downloaded from the web...It does seem that delay has been available to the jQuery library since version 1.4 though.

<code>
// Delay Plugin for jQuery
// - http://www.evanbot.com
// - © 2008 Evan Byrne

jQuery.fn.delay = function(time,func){
 this.each(function(){
  setTimeout(func,time);
 });
 
 return this;
};</code>
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydiv').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydiv').hide('fast');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var whateverKeyCode = 13; // enter
var nSeconds = 5;

$(document.body).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == whateverKeyCode) {
        setTimeoute($("#divID").hide(0),1000*nSeconds); // 5 seconds
    }
});
```

that should work I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The documented form of this for jQuery would look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/calebgray/7nzFX/).